# mailapp cannot send email

Tags: email, google-sheets

I am having a problem with Google Sheets and MailApp.sendEmail. It works if I execute the method using run in the script editor. When I actually try to execute the javascript method within the spreadsheet (onEdit) it does not send the email. I know the method is executing because the I call setActiveSheet and that is executing correctly.

Thanks!

Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W7cdPdwZA9cx847_yVDqpDM_eii02sxGMc8qh7xO6sE/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my script:

```
function onEdit() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Pass"));
   var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Pass");
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 1);
   // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
   var data = dataRange.getValues();

   var row = data[0];
   var student = row[0];  // First column
   MailApp.sendEmail("brucemortland@gmail.com", "Robotics Club", 
       student);
   } 

function onOpen() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ID');
   sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
   ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Pass"));
   }
```

Comment: When MailApp is used at ``onEdit()``, it has to be installed as a trigger. Under without the trigger, when it confirms the execution transcript at script editor after edited spreadsheet, do you find the authorization error at sendEmail? In this case, please install a trigger for ``onEdit()``. On the script editor -> Edit -> Current project's triggers -> Click add one now -> Select onEdit, From spreadsheet, Edit. -> Click save. The detail information is here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Tanaike, You were spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.